# Flutter Google Maps app throws exception and crashes in browser , but not on Android

Tags: google-maps, flutter, browser

I am using [this code](https://github.com/whatsupcoders/Flutter-GoogleMaps), which accompanies [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNqEfnnmoHk) popular YouTube tutorial. It is part of a  large series, with lots of views, so I would expect it to be good code. Also, it runs just fine on Android.

I followed the official [Building a web application with Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web), but, when I launch my app in the browser, it crashes.

Here's the trace before the crash:

> dart.developer.registerExtension ext.flutter.inspector.getChildren
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getChildrenSummaryTree
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getChildrenDetailsSubtree
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getRootWidget developer_patch.dart:65:72
>   dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getRootRenderObject developer_patch.dart:65:72
>   dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getRootWidgetSummaryTree
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getDetailsSubtree developer_patch.dart:65:72
>   dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getSelectedRenderObject
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getSelectedWidget developer_patch.dart:65:72
>   dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.getSelectedSummaryWidget
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.isWidgetCreationTracked
>   developer_patch.dart:65:72 dart.developer.registerExtension
>   ext.flutter.inspector.screenshot developer_patch.dart:65:72
>   dart.developer.postEvent Flutter.FrameworkInitialization {}
>   developer_patch.dart:98:16

It crashes at the call to `super()` in the following code (dart_sdk.js, line 6327)

```
  dart.DartError = class DartError extends Error {
    constructor(error) {
      super();
      if (error == null) error = new core.NullThrownError.new();
      this[dart._thrownValue] = error;
      if (error != null && typeof error == "object" && error[dart._jsError] == null) {
        error[dart._jsError] = this;
      }
    }
    get message() {
      return dart.toString(this[dart._thrownValue]);
    }
  };
```

here's the call stack

> console.trace() debugger eval code:1:9
>        debugger eval code:1
>       DartError dart_sdk.js:6327
>       throw_ errors.dart:216
>       decodeEnvelope message_codecs.dart:569
>       _invokeMethod platform_channel.dart:156
>       onValue async_patch.dart:47
>       runUnary zone.dart:1439
>       handleValue future_impl.dart:141
>       handleValueCallback future_impl.dart:686
>       _propagateToListeners future_impl.dart:715
>       _completeWithValue future_impl.dart:526
>        future_impl.dart:560
>       _microtaskLoop schedule_microtask.dart:43
>       _startMicrotaskLoop schedule_microtask.dart:52
>       _scheduleImmediateWithPromise async_patch.dart:168

Question: is there anything I can do about this? I don't see any reference to "my" code (since its asynch), nor any way to find if it is a problem in "my code". It runs just fine on Android.

[Update] I also tried it with the simplest possible static map, albeit iwht a single marker, and got the same result.

Do I have to accept that Flutter for the web is on the Beta Channel and leave it a few months to see if it stabilizes? Or, does someone have a browser based Flutter Google Maps demo?

Answer (score 1):

The offical flutter google maps plugin doesn't support web right now and it is still in developers preview

Use this plugin to works with google maps on web.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_maps

Don't forget to add script tags in index.html in body which are provided by plugin's readme. Add them and everything works fine.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, and upvote. I will let the bounty run for 4 more days, but will probably award it to you. Since most of my apps involve maps (Leaflet with AngluarJs until now), I am not really sure why I would consider switching to Flutter at this time, although it does look very, very, promising. I do hear claims that Mapbox will work both mobile & web, so will look into that. Thanks gain for your help.

Comment: Flutter web is in beta but have more issues than windows or linux apps. So don't use flutter web right now. Flutter day is coming soon may be they will answer when the stable version is released as i seen lots of tweets about flutter web. I'm also waiting for flutter web stable. Mapbox and leaflet plugins are available but i didn't found any official plugin.

Comment: I have awarded you the answer and the bounty. Since maps are "must have" for me, not "nice to have", I will not be using Flutter, which is sad, but must be. I will revisit the situation at 6 monthly intervals. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am using Angular***JS***, not Angular {TypeScript)